# plostly histogram facet row animation frame

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Here is a sample of my data:

> Time,Value,Name,Type
> 0,6.9,A,start
> 40,6.9,A,start
> 60,6.9,A,start
> 0,0.01,B,start
> 40,0.01,B,start
> 60,0.01,B,start
> 0,1.0,C,start
> 40,1.0,C,start
> 60,1.0,C,start
> 0,0.08,D,start
> 40,0.08,D,start
> 60,0.08,D,start
> 0,0.000131,E,End
> 40,0.00032,E,End
> 60,0.99209,E,End
> 0,0.002754,F,End
> 40,0.00392,F,End
> 60,0.01857,F,End
> 0,0.003,G,End
> 40,0.00516,G,End
> 60,0.00746,G,End
> 0,0.00426,H,End
> 40,0.0043,H,End
> 60,0.0095,H,End
> 0,0,I,End
> 40,0.0017,I,End
> 60,0.0183,I,End

And my code below:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('tohistogram.csv')
fig_bar = px.histogram(df,x='Name',y='Value',animation_frame='Time',color='Name',facet_row='Type')
fig_bar.update_layout(yaxis_title="value") 
fig_bar.update_xaxes(matches=None)
fig_bar.for_each_xaxis(lambda xaxis: xaxis.update(showticklabels=True))
fig_bar.show()
```

`
Fig1:
[image]

Fig2:
[image]

With the data point listed above, I wanted 2 histogram separated by type (start,end) in one frame with one animation_frame
Tried the above code, as one can see from the image I could partial achieve but from Fig1: second histogram has (A,B,C,D),excepted just E to I.
2. Figure 2 was when I played the run button and auto scaled then I see A-D are gone and only E-I,
This is what I wanted to achieve in the first place itself, before running 2 histogram should sort as per 'Type'
A. Is it possible I tried couple of things like removed color
fig_bar = px.histogram(df,x='Name',y='Value',animation_frame='Time',facet_row='Type')
histogram sorts as per 'Type' of course no color but no label in second x-axis.
[image]

B.fig_bar = px.histogram(df,x='Name',y='Value',color='Name',facet_row='Type')
It sorts but no animation
[image]

What I am trying is it possible?
need 2 histogram with in the same frame sorted by 'Type',color and animation_frame?

C. Only if possible then, how to label y-axis of the first histogram from sumofValues to user-defined axis name and also have its own axis range.

D.I didn't come across any example but on the histogram, on mouse hover can I show another simple line graph image instead of text or value?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I switched from histogram to bar and rest was the same

```
fig_bar = px.bar(df,x='Name',y='Value',animation_frame='Time',color='Name',facet_row='Type')
```

I could fix section A,B,C

But D I am yet to get example for hover either for histogram or Bar Chart